# Why Use SendGrid (And Other Services)

Tags: php, api, sendgrid

I was installing the SendGrid PHP library and noticed that it also installed swiftmailer.

That got me to ask why use SendGrid instead of SwiftMailer or other libraries to send emails?

What technical benefits does using a third party email deliverer give over sending mail from of the server using a library?

Do people use it for the analytics, or does it provide guarantee in email delivery chain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Although not directly related to your question, the SendGrid PHP library no longer uses SwiftMailer. It instead makes use of the SendGrid Web API, which has it's own host of benefits. You may want to look into using the most recent version of the library: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

Comment: SwiftMailer is just the transport mechanism. It isn't a server. You can't send emails with only SwiftMailer, you have to point it to an SMTP server. SendGrid provides the server component so you don't have to set one up yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and guiding me in asking better questions on SO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Deliverability**: Avoid relegation to the spam folder and rejection by mail servers.

**Throughput**: Handle large volumes.

**Analytics & Transparency**: Track email performance, reads, etc and verify whether emails have reached their destination.

**OptOuts**: Ability to prevent mailing to certain addresses in a separate layer, rather than relying on applications.